# Can't get spring cors working with angular and kotlin

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I can't seem to get cors to work with sping/kotlin and Angular 10. I have tried just about everything I can find online. I have added the cors annotations to the controller, api and globally but none of them work. Any ideas?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurationSupport() {

    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        println("HHHHHHH")
        registry.addMapping("/**")
    }
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://localhost:4200"])
@RestController
class StoreController(
        private val repo: TaskRepository
) {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/test")
    fun testGet(): List<String> {
        val op = ChromeOptions()
        val user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
        op.addArguments("user-agent={$user_agent}")
        op.addArguments("headless")
        val driver = ChromeDriver(op)
        driver.get("https://www.nordstrom.com/s/creme-de-la-mer-moisturizing-cream/3057002?origin=coordinating-3057002-0-2-GIFTS_FOR_HER_1-recbot-top_hits_womens_gifts&recs_placement=GIFTS_FOR_HER_1&recs_strategy=top_hits_womens_gifts&recs_source=recbot&recs_page_type=home&recs_seed=0&color=NO%20COLOR")
        var images = emptyList<String>()
        var count = AtomicInteger(0)
        while(images.isEmpty() && count.get() < 100) {
            Thread.sleep(300)
            count.addAndGet(1)
            images = driver.findElementsByTagName("img")
                    .filter{ (it.size.width > 250 && it.size.height > 250) }.map { it.getAttribute("src") }
        }
        return images
    }
}
```

Here is the angular code

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/test/", { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had spring security libraries in my gradle and that doesn't play nice with cors annotations.